# Paypal Payment - Express Checkout page not reachable

Tags: payment-processor, paypal

I'm starting testing the Paypal payment cicle.
After setting **both** paypal forms with the following data:

- User [Name my paypal UN]
- Password  [my paypal PW]
- Signature [my paypal SG]
- Site URL https://www.paypal.com/
- API URL  https://api-3t.paypal.com/
- Recurring Payments URL [empty]
- Button URL https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif

Then I created a New Contribution Page, setting "Paypal" as processor and unchecked the "Use a confirmation page" flag.

So, when i test the payment on the Contribution Page,

- I'm redirected in the Paypal page and I proceed entering my Credit Card data
- I'm unexpectedly ("Use a confirmation page" flag was unchecked!) returned on a new Civicrm Page. From here i press the [Make a contribution] button
- the following URL "http://opigi.net/modimp/civicrm/index.php?q=civicrm/contribute/transact" is called with the content "*The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.*"

I called the Paypal call-center, they told me that the firs part of the operation is correctly terminate, but the page civicrm page where the **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** is not reached.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

15:21: After some other test, done comparing my test site with a production site, I discovered how in the sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Payment\PayPalImpl.php:

- in my local test, where the flow ends correctly, the API **GetExpressCheckoutDetails** is called two times and finally also the API **DoExpressCheckoutPayment**
- in my production site after the first **GetExpressCheckoutDetails** call, I get the error "*The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable ...*"

Comment: Hi Marcello - can you confirm what version of civi you are using and whether you also have the pay later option enabled and/or if you have more than one payment processor enabled on the page?

Comment: Hi Meir. 
I have 4.7 Drupal Civi installed, no other processor on and the pay later option is off. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi, the name is actually Tamar :-), but from your response, it looks like I am at a loss to help you any further - my apologies.